# CSS how to add sliding transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following fiddle demo of a working sidenav menu with sliding sub menu contents. I followed the same demo without using Jquery (actually first using plain JS and then via CSS hover selector instead of click) and in my case sub menu doesn't slides/animates in the same way.

```
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.parent:hover .submenu,.submeun:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Is that animation due to Jquery toggle method?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
         $('.submenu').toggle('visible');
     });
  });
```

How can I replicate the same approach without using jquery, via css or plain JS as I don't want to use jquery just for one simple sliding animation.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j6zaLns5/1/)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The child `ul` needs to be placed within a `li`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way ?

```js
document.getElementById('home').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var nextEl = e.target.nextElementSibling;

  if(!nextEl.classList.contains('submenu')) {
    return false;
  }

  if(nextEl.classList.contains('show')) {
     nextEl.classList.remove('show')
  }
  else {
     nextEl.classList.add('show');
  }
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
  -ms-transition: max-height 1s;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  background: #e5feff;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
.submenu.show {
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li id="home" class="parent">Home</li>
    <li class="submenu"><ul >
      <li>Home 1</li>
      <li>Home 2</li>
      <li>Home 3</li>
    </ul>   </li>
    <li>Explore</li>
  </ul>                  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `slideToggle()` and so avoid changing classes . This is just an option

Also , keep in mind that a submenu must be inside the parent li, for example `<li>Home<ul><li>Sub link</li></ul></li>` . I changed your HTML accordingly

see snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
         $(this).children(".submenu").slideToggle()
     });
  });
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    background: #DF314D;  
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 35px;
    color: white;
}

#sidebar li:hover { 
    background: #C9223D;
}

.submenu {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="parent">Home  
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Home 1</li>
      <li>Home 2</li>
      <li>Home 3</li>
    </ul>   
    </li>
    <li>Explore</li>
  </ul>                  
</div>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I can't use jquery.

Comment: oh. i saw what you tried. i saw your tags. didn't read all the way